# QStackedWidget - Change page one by one

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qt-designer, qstackedwidget

Is there a way to change the page of a QStackedWidget without appointing to the actual index.

```
self.homeb.clicked.connect(lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0))
```

So instead of just using a button to go directly to the appointed index 0, I want to navigate through them, my intentions are to create a "next", "previous" "home" function.

Comment: `self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(self.stackedWidget.currentIndex() + 1)`, etc.

Comment: Perfect, that worked flawlessly! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
 self.homeb_3.clicked.connect(lambda: self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(self.stackedWidget.currentIndex() + 1))
```